# Cant cout a string

Tags: c++

I am using this code

```
#include <iostream>

class person
{
    class address
    {
    public:
        std::string addr;
        int pobox;

        address()
        {
            addr = "Some Address";
            pobox = 200;
        }
    };

    address a;;

    void Test()
    {
        std::cout << a.addr; //ERROR
    }
};

int main()
{
}
```

I get this error

> Error 1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

Any suggestions on how i can fix it ?

Comment: You forgot to include <string>...

Comment: Yes that was the reason. But why do i have to include string. Normally i simply include iostream and cout has no problem displaying strings

Comment: [works](http://ideone.com/Ippt9b) for me

Comment: its possible some implementations of iostream include string internally. that being said, you should include the headers you need and *not* rely on this behavior.

Comment: Because you are using a `std::string`. If you have something like `std::cout << "hello world";` you are using a different kind of string which doesn't need an `include` - `"hello world"` is called a string literal, and is implemented as an array of `const char`s

Comment: `Yes that was the reason. But why do i have to include string.`  In this implementation, it is `std::string` that knows how to write itself to a stream using `operator <<`.  The <iostream> knows nothing about `std::string`, nor what it means when it sees a `std::string` being used in a stream operation.   Imagine if you created a class that has overloaded operator <<.  If you failed to include your class, do you think that iostream knows about your overload?  It doesn't.  Same thing here.

Comment: String is not a built in type, and so you need to include the library for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides including the `<string>` header as mentioned, I think the rest needs to be fixed, like follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class person {
    class address {
    public: // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        std::string addr;
        int pobox;

        address() {
            addr = "Some Address";
            pobox = 200;
        }
    };

    address a;

public: // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    void Test() {
        std::cout << a.addr;
    }
};

int main() {
    person p;
    p.Test();
    return 0;
}
```

<sub>See the [**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/t3qdm4).</sub>

You'll need to make the class members in question publicly visible, to instantiate or call them.
You may declare `address` as a nested type of person (at least `public` to become useful), though I'm not so sure that this is such a good idea.

---

The much better approach seems to be declaring a own, self contained `address` class outside of `person`, and have the latter one contain a member for it:

```
class address {
public:

    address() : addr_("Some Address"), pobox_(200) {}

    const std::string& addr() const { return addr_; }
    void addr(std::string value) { addr_ = value; }

    int pobox() const { return pobox_; }
    void pobox(int value ) { pobox_ = value; }

private:
    std::string addr_;
    int pobox_;
};

class person {
    address a_;
public:
    void Test() {
        std::cout << "Address: " << a_.addr() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "PO Box : " << a_.pobox() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    person p;
    p.Test();
    return 0;
}
```

<sub>See another [**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/mfYj0h).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You may want to do an include for string:

```
#include <string>
```